# Event for Text Selection in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vsx

I am writing an addin for Visual Studio 2008. I need to know when some text (code) is selected in Text Editor. I have not been able to find any events for that. For example, when somebody selects some code using mouse or keyboard in the class file, how can I get notified that some text/code has been selected?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think that considering the number of different selection I make while writing code, that could occur quite frquently.  Also I'm pretty sure there is always a length zero selection active on the cursor.

Comment: You are right, and I understand the overhead. But I have a particular need to capture this event. I did a little more digging and it looks like it may not be possible. The only thing I have been able to find is the `TextEditorEvents`. And this only has one event exposed - `LineChanged`, which occurs when changes are made to a line in the Text/Code Editor that moves the insertion point. I wish they had more events in the TextEditorEvents class.